# Win Forms .Net provide an SSL Cert at run time for HTTPListener NO CERT STORE

Tags: .net, ssl

Is it possible to provide an SSL Cert at run time for a HTTPListener to use rather then pull it from the cert store?

In my use of TCP listeners I have managed to do this. I can embed the cert as a resource in the project and then provide it to the listener when it is started. This easily lends itself to generating a unique SSL cert for every connection.

Though it triggers a cert validation error I then have to override. But all I am aiming for is the encryption over network.

---------------REASONS--------------------
Well these are not applications that run over the internet.  They run under private vpns and secure lan environments.   The only reason to do this is to avoid security messages from the browser clients and for the encryption.   Cert expiration is a non issue if if you tell it to expire in 200 years.

It would be impossible for someone to fake the hosting of the mobile apps server since its on an isolated lan that doesn't have internet access.  And even if they did the time involved would yield little gain.

This is mainly for mobile UPC scanner devices at a specific location.  That I am managing from a HTTPListener on an in-house server.

It is also to avoid the whole tangled mess of registering CERTS in the store through a secondary application.

So far the best I have seen is automating the cert store entry and port binding of the cert.  Or I write my own HTTPListenerClass derived from the TCPListener.... but I really dont want to do that.

Would much rather override properties of the underlying TCP connection in the HTTPListener if that is possible.

Comment: What are you going to do when the certificate *expires*? `Though it triggers a cert validation error` well, no client is goint to trust your certificate. Browsers will mark your entpoind as insecure too.

Comment: *Why* are you doing this? On a domain, you can easily use the domain's Certificate Services to create and use trusted certificates.

Comment: This may not run under a Domain....... so relying on a domain would not be practical.

Comment: Using an untrusted certificate isn't practical. Current *Browsers* will scream to high heaven if they find an invalid certificate. Asking your customers to disable certificate verification isn't good for credibility. The user's certificate store already contains valid certificates that *can't* be compromised with a simple file copy. You can get valid free certificates with Let's Encrypt that are very easy to install and renew automatically

Comment: Furthermore, yes, you do have a very serious issue with certificate with a long expiration date - they'll be hacked. If you want extra security *on top* of a VPN, this is a bad move. If you just want to fool the customers' browsers - don't. As I said, it's very easy to get valid certificates with automatic renewal

Comment: If a device can't authenticate against a cert provider because it doesnt have internet access how would it verify it?

Comment: If I generate a new certificate for every communication... how would they be hacked?

Comment: I just want to encrypt the communication so tools like wire shark can not see passwords going across their LAN....  it is rather impractical, that some one would spend the time to access this system.   And the system is not open to the internet.

Comment: SSL btw has already been proven to be hackable.... so even if you use certified certs from a vendor.... there is no guarantee that you wont be hacked.... so your arguments are invalid.......I just want to encrypt the communications.

Comment: No it hasn't. You are confusing HTTPS with specific encryption algorithms. SSL v3 is deprecated because it is weak, replaced by TLS 1.2 which is considered secure. All of these work *through certificates*. to *encrypt communications* in order to avoid *man-in-the-middle* attacks. That works because the data is *short-lived* and the *certificate expires*. Otherwise an attacker could gather enough samples to break long-lived connections or certificates

Comment: I'm not making arguments. That's how encryption works. If you want to do things differently, make sure you understand how they work in the first place and what it is you want to improve.

Comment: My question pertained to issuing certs on the server side to a client with out having to enter it in the server sides cert store.... clients browsers will probably require such.

In a tcp connection you can provide the cert with out having to enter it in the cert store because you can push the file directly into the TCP/SSL connection.

For HTTPS it appears that you have to bind the cert it to the port through netsh http command and it looks up the certs thumbprint in the store.